# Getting Error Cannot fork() a new process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2

I am working on ruby on rails and I am facing this problem on my site's apache error log after some time and apache stops working and after restarting apache it works.

```
ERROR: Cannot fork() a new process: Cannot allocate memory (errno=12) 
                                             in apache2 error log
```

I have searched for this and I found "update the passenger to fixed this issue". I have updated passenger but my problem is not fixed. Can anybody help me to fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: How much memory do you have available on the machine?

Comment: Thank you for reply. About 11GB memory is available on machine and RAM is 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but this is how I resolved it. I renamed Gemfile.lock to Gemfile.lock_2 (Just for backup).

Then:

```
bundle install
```

I restarted the server, and the issue was resolved.